# How can I record the two time stamps when executing DFS without using recurrence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

When executing `DFS` in a graph, it is important to track when a node has been visited and when all the neighbors of the node has been visited, using two time stamps. Sometimes we need to record the two time stamps. I have already known how to do it using recurrence. But I have problems when trying it without recurrence (using e.g. loops and stacks) to write a `DFS` function.

I have tried the common iterative `DFS` method:

```cpp
    unsigned int time = 0;
    stack<int> nodeStack = stack<int>();
    vector<int> nodeVec = vector<int>(graph.size(), null); // null means not visited
    vector<pair<int, int>> nodeTimeStamp = vector<pair<int, int>>(graph.size(), pair<int, int>{0, 0});
    list<int> firstTimeList = list<int>();
    list<int> lastTimeList = list<int>();
    bool isAcyclic = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++) {
        if (nodeVec.at(i) == null) {
            stack<int> nodeStack = stack<int>();
            nodeStack.push(i);
            firstTimeList.push_front(i);
            nodeTimeStamp.at(i).first = time ++;
            nodeVec.at(i) = visited;
            while (!nodeStack.empty()) {
                auto u = nodeStack.top();
                if (nodeVec.at(u) == discovered) {
                    lastTimeList.push_front(u);
                    nodeTimeStamp.at(u).second = time ++;
                    nodeStack.pop();
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < graph.at(u).size(); j++) {
                    int v = graph.at(u).at(j).first;
                    if (nodeVec.at(v) == null) {
                        nodeStack.push(v);
                        firstTimeList.push_front(v);
                        nodeTimeStamp.at(v).first = time ++;
                        nodeVec.at(v) = visited;
                    }
                    else
                        isAcyclic = false;
                }
                nodeVec.at(u) = discovered;
            }
        }
    }
```

It does not work because it will push one node's all neighbors into the stack when searching. So we cannot record when one node is visited this way. Could you please help me with an idea to record the two time stamps when executing `DFS` **without using recurrence**?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but wouldn't recording the timestamp as you `pop()` the nodes from the stack (as opposed to when you `push()` them on it) in the first example give you what you want?

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand you. My code (the second code segment) is based on the first segment but it failed.

Comment: I was addressing why you think the first code sample "does not work well". It performs a textbook DFS, so it feels like you were a lot closer to making that work than you think.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it seemingly more clear. Sorry again to say that my English is not so good.

Comment: I have edited the question as you said. Thanks for your suggestion!